# C++ catch exception in a loop and rethrow _after_ the loop finishes?

Tags: c++, c++11, exception

The goal is to fully process a loop and throw any exception that may have occurred afterwards:

```
for (...) {
   try {
      // code that could throw
   } catch (const ExceptionObj &ex) {
      // save ex and rethrow after the loop
   }
}
```

What would be the best practice for doing this? Saving *any* of the exceptions is ok in my particular case.

A couple of ideas that I have:

1. Copy `ex` to an `ExceptionObj` value. Problem: doesn't scale well at all when ex has subclasses or more exceptions need to be handled.
2. Have a `clone` method in `ExceptionObj` that returns a copy on the heap. Problem: doesn't work for third party exceptions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Handling a thrown exception object in such a type-erased way is what [`std::exception_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception_ptr) exists for:

```
std::exception_ptr ex;
for (...) {
   try {
      // code that could throw
   } catch (...) {
      ex = std::current_exception();
   }
}
if(ex) // Only evaluates to true if a thrown exception was assigned to it.
    std::rethrow_exception(ex);
```

All the lifetime concerns related to the dynamic type of the exception object are handled by the standard library. You can think of `ex` as a reference counted handle to the exception object, allowing you to hoist it out of the try-catch block.

This follows the approach you laid out in your post and then confirmed in a comment, that the last exception thrown is the one that gets re-thrown.

Comment: some nitpicking: depending on implementation (and conditions) you may end up with: 1. std::bad_alloc (or std::bad_exception) being re-thrown instead of user exception; 2. unspecified behavior, if there is no memory to allocate another exception object at various points where it (another object) can be thrown. Granted, all of this can happen only when heap is (nearly) exhausted. Plus, you may end up with guaranteed call of exception cctor... If it always throws smth else -- you will never be able to rethrow your original exception.